# set the selectbox value dynamically using angular2 reactive forms

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using angular2 reactive forms for building forms. But how do i set the selectbox value dynamically.(i want 'VPA' should pre-select dynamically)

```
<form [formGroup]="addBeneficiaryForm">
    <ion-item>
                <ion-label stacked>Type</ion-label>                    
                <ion-select [formControl]="type">
                  <ion-option value="VPA">VPA</ion-option>
                  <ion-option value="MMID">MMID/MOBILE</ion-option>                 
                </ion-select>
              </ion-item>
       </form>
```

I try to set in the following way, but not working.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'addbenificiary',
  templateUrl: 'addbenificiary.html' 
})
export class AddBeneficiaryPage {
  addBeneficiaryForm: FormGroup;
  type: AbstractControl;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.addBeneficiaryForm = fb.group({     
       'type': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]         
    }); 
  }
 public ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.addBeneficiaryForm.controls['type'].setValue('VPA');
 }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you initialize it when you create it? Like this: `'type': ['VPA', Validators.compose([Validators.required])] `

Comment: i am using for some other purpose i.e, edit form handling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use `formControlName` instead of `[formControl]`:

```
<ion-select formControlName="type">
```

Comment: nice catch @AJT_82!

Comment: @sebaferreras Thanks, I have my (rare) moments :D :D